# Flash - Error 1014

Tags: flash, apache-flex

```
error 1014 class mx.core application could not be found.
```

Hi guys,
My client get's the errormessage posted above, and I don't understand why.

The application runs well on all of our machines here, and it used to work with previous versions of this app (in fact, I didn't add code to the app, only edited XML files which contains our assets, to include new assets).

What causes this error? I did upgrade to AIR3.3 a week ago or so, where I had to overwrite some files, but this app is coded using Flex SDK 3.6, so it shoudl't affect it, right?

Also, it does work on our other workstations inhouse, which is stock.. So I dont understand why they are getting this error now all of a sudden.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

EDIT:
Ok, so when I got to our client and checked the problem, I figured out he tried to run it from within the zipped archive. Obviously doesnt work..

At least I learned a bit about RSL and such! =)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is that a runtime error or a compile time error?  Are you compiling your app using RSLs?  Could your client's network be blocking the URLs for loading the signed SWZ Files from Adobe?

Comment: Ahh, sorry. It's a runtime error. Compiling works fine, and it runs smooth on all of our systems. Even tried it at home now on my laptop, and it plays as it should.

RSL? Probably not, since I dont know what it is =)
This is most likely a problem on the clientæs side, as it works on every computer i try here..

The network might be blocking internett access, yes. But does it need that? All is loaded locally, as far as I know. Not sure about the SWZ files though..

Comment: I suggest doing some research into RSLs to be sure, as I believe that is the default in 3.6.  You can check the properties on your Flash Builder project to be sure, though.  If you are compiling your app using RSLs, then yes network access is needed to download the signed SWZ files from Adobe.

Comment: framework_3.6.0.16995.SWZ - This file is included in the root folder when I build my app. Does it still need to go online to check? (or is that the wrong file)? All is default, and it's always worked before. Going to meet them tomorrow to check it out.

Comment: and thats the only file included.. I can see from other programs Iæve made using FLex SDK 4.5.1 that I have more .swf files included.. Are there somewhere I can download the "missing" files? And just copy them over to the application folder?

Comment: You'll have to read up on RSLs (The SWZ file is a special RSL signed by Adobe). I'm unclear how it all works at runtime; but I'm still guessing that this is part of the problem.  You can switch your project to "merge into code" for the framework and see if that build still shows errors to your client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the client had forgotten to extract the archive, so he was trying to run the program from within the zipped archive. ;)

At least I learned a bit about RSLs! Thanks to www.Flextras.com